# How to make pickle-friend object id in Python?

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to persist some Python objects with Python `pickle` module, these objects uses

```
id(object)
```

as their external identifiers (e.g., on a web page).

The problem is, I find that after a `pickle dump/load cycle`, `id(object)` value changes. That makes `id(object)` unusable for external identifier which expects unchanging values.

So how can I conveniently creating an `id` that is not changed after `pickle/unpickle`?

Comment: FWIW, using the id probably isn't a good idea anyway.  You can't guarantee that the id's are unique since the id is only guaranteed to be unique for the lifetime of the object.  If one object gets garbage collected, another object can "take it's place" and pick up that free id.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Documentation for `id`:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long
>   integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object
>   during its lifetime.

So two different objects (i.e. if `a is not b` is `True`) have two different ids.

Alternatives:

(1) If your type is hashable, you can use `hash`:

```
hash((1,2,3))
```

(2) Only a few things are hashable, but you could hash the pickle, e.g.

```
hash(pickle.dumps([1,2,3]))
```

(3) You could explicitly set an `id` attribute for each object.

Comment: @mgilson, sort of. If you use the full hash, not something like `hash(x) % 100`, then you need a hash once you've gotten struck by lightening while winning the lottery.

Comment: @PaulDraper: Actual hash collisions aren't that uncommon. Even if the hashes were perfectly random, you'd only need about 80000 objects before the probability of collision rises above 50%.

Comment: Also, hashes aren't guaranteed to be consistent across executions. They usually are, but they might not be on different interpreter settings or a different interpreter.

Comment: @user2357112, true. It depends on their use. If you have 2 objects, the probability (in CPython, 64-bit) is less than 0.0000000000000000001. In the general case, though, 64-bits are far from enough. The consistency across interpreters is the bigger downside.

Comment: hash() doesn't work. Because its give different hash in different session.